# Why is my json parser storing all data instead of just the average?

Tags: c++

I am trying to have it where my code stores in a vector all of the average of a stock price every minute of one day, I am using an API to do this which gives me json format of "average" "close" "date" etc. but i am just wanting the float behind the average to be stored. Below is my code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < chartData.size(); i++)
    {
        time[i] = startTime + 3600*i;
        price.push_back(chartData[i]["average"].asDouble());
        data[i] = fastWriter.write(chartData[i]);
        cout << "Average " << i << ": " << data[i] << endl;
    }
```

and this is the output it gives

[image]

What am I doing wrong with my code for it to being do this when all i want is the average value from the json data?

Comment: Did you mean to do `data[i] = fastWriter.write(price.back());`?

Comment: @Frank Ahh okay that was a dumb mistake, so .back() just outputs what was jsut set as price[] and the nthat loop ends and restarts and price gets assigned something new and price.back() is ran thus giving it a new value?

Comment: `.back()` returns the last element of the vector.

Comment: @Frank So in price.push_back(chartData[i]["average"]).asDouble, basically the first iteration of the foor loop is chartData[0] so it goes to the first json format line and finds "average" and stores it as the first element in the vector, and then it just goes down the list doing the same thing until it reaches the bottom, but then how would i say price[359] or the 359th element in the vector? Sorry im new to vectors and we were only taught arrays oddly enough.